# Paperclip gem Rails [6.1] : migration error wrong number of arguments (given 3, expected 2)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows, version, paperclip

Im trying to install paperclip gem on my rails app and I had 3 problems in succession and I would like to point out to them, it may be related to the last problem :

1- I coulden't install the paperclip dependency "mimemagic" => I solved it by adding the file `freedesktop.org.xml.in` and its variable `FREEDESKTOP_MIME_TYPES_PATH` to my windows machine.

2 - Then after initializing paperclip I couldn't do the migration => I solved it by adding the version of my rails app which is [6.1] bessid the Active record so it become `class AddAttachmentImageToPics < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.1]`.

3- The last problem which Im stuck in is when I type `rails db:migrate` I get this message that says :

```
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 3, expected 2)
```

This is the content of my migration file :

```
class AddAttachmentImageToPics < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.1]
  def self.up
    change_table :pics do |t|
      t.attachment :image
    end
  end

  def self.down
    remove_attachment :pics, :image
  end
end
```

the message in cmd :

```
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Ruby\instagrameme>rails db:migrate
== 20220205102326 AddAttachmentImageToPics: migrating =========================
-- change_table(:pics)
rails aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

wrong number of arguments (given 3, expected 2)
C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/Ruby/instagrameme/db/migrate/20220205102326_add_attachment_image_to_pics.rb:4:in `block in up'
C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/Ruby/instagrameme/db/migrate/20220205102326_add_attachment_image_to_pics.rb:3:in `up'

Caused by:
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 3, expected 2)
C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/Ruby/instagrameme/db/migrate/20220205102326_add_attachment_image_to_pics.rb:4:in `block in up'
C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/Ruby/instagrameme/db/migrate/20220205102326_add_attachment_image_to_pics.rb:3:in `up'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [when I use paperclip migration error occur](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66331614/when-i-use-paperclip-migration-error-occur)

Comment: I'm still stuck here for the whole week , any suggestion how to upload images to a website using rails framework

Comment: have you tried the solutions given in the above so post which I shared?

Comment: Yeah I tried it , the migration did happened, but the uploading file process didn't work for me , I still don't know how developers are using Paperclip 6.1 with Ruby 3 and Rails 6.1

Answer (score 6):

I think [this](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/blob/c769382c9b7078f3d1620b50ec2a70e91ba62ec4/lib/paperclip/schema.rb#L54) is the root cause of your issue. The `column` method used took 3 arguments in [rails 5](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1.7/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/TableDefinition.html#method-i-column), but the 3rd argument got changed to a keyword argument in [rails 6](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v6.0.0/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/TableDefinition.html#method-i-column). This is an issue for `ruby >= 2.7` because they removed automatic conversion of a hash to keyword arguments.

You would probably need to fork or monkey patch paperclip to fix this issue.